# Mongoose: search for ObjectID by Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aws-documentdb

I want to filter my collection by aggregation for one of many ObjectIDs.

Because of some DocumentDB restrictions I can not build a single pipeline with uncorrelated subqueries. So my fix is to do it in two queries.

for example: I have an aggregation that returns all teamIds, for some conditions as an array of Object with the IDs.

```
[{_id: ObjectID("abcdef")}, {_id: ObjectID("ghijkl")}, {_id: ObjectID("vwxyz")}, ...]
```

I now want to have a second aggregation filter another collection using the ObjectIDs.

This would work in Mongo Compass:

```
{
  "team": {
    "$in": [ObjectId("60aabcb05c7462f42b3d7zyx"), ObjectId("60aabc7b05c7462f42b3dxyz")]
  },
  ....
}
```

My issue is that i can not find the correct syntax for JS to generate such a pipeline.
What ever I try, JS always converts my Array of ObjectIDs to something like this:

```
{
  "team": {
    "$in": [{
      "_id": "60aabcb05c7462f42b3d7zyx"
    },{
      "_id": "60aabc7b05c7462f42b3dxyz"
    }]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this. I am not 100% why this syntax works because it is still just an array of objects, formatted like before, but I guess there is some stuff mongoose does, that is opaque to me.

```
let teams = await TeamMgmt.getTeamsAggregatedByFilter( teamFilter )

// make an array of ObjectIds so we can filter for them.
let idArray = []
Object.keys( teams ).map( function ( key, index ) {
    idArray.push( new mongoose.Types.ObjectId( teams[ index ]._id.toString() ) )
} );

const shiftFilter = [
    {
      '$match': {
          'team': {
              "$in": idArray
          },
          ....
    }
```